# C register calling conventions

Tags: c, assembly

Where i can find documentation about registers which assembly must preserve when a C function is called?

Comment: In your processor's/compiler's manual.

Comment: In your compilers help or on the compiler vendors web site.

Comment: No portable code from a compiler to another one under the same system?

Comment: Code generated for the same platform and the same operating system should be portable. All compiler vendors should implement the same ABI for that system.

Comment: it varies based on the compiler and processor, next time specify both please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dr Agner Fogs optimization manuals contain a nifty side-by-side listing of all the common system and compiler conventions(ABIs), for both 32 and 64 bits. They also contain a lot of other useful information, you can get them here: http://www.agner.org/optimize/

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was searching.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is your system's C Application Binary Interface. Google for "C ABI" and your architecture, and you'll find it. For example, [here](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~maccabe/classes/341/labman/node12.html) is one for sparc and [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_reg_usage) is the relevant bit for AVRs.

Answer (score 4):

This is called the *ABI* (Application Binary Interface). Where do you find it? Depends on your architecture and operating system.

For example: [Google for `ABI x86_64 linux`](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=ABI%20x86_64%20linux%20) if you want to find the calling conventions for an 64 bit linux system.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of calling conventions in use, but the most common is [CDECL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). The arguments are pushed on the stack in the order described by that link, and the "scratch" registers available to the callee are `%eax`, `%ecx`, and `%edx`. Anything else should be preserved on the stack.

But, as other people have pointed out, this is only one of many conventions. Check the documentation for the system you're programming for.

Comment: This answer only makes any sense on an Intel platform. Admittedly, that's probably what the OQ is using, but they didn't say.

Comment: Right; I'm playing under the assumption that if the OP didn't think it was important to state the hardware, he's probably just playing around on his own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this links:

[Using Win32 calling conventions](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv.html)

[Intel x86 Function-call Conventions - Assembly View](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much architecture specific. Have a look at wikipedia's explanation for starters.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention